# Run emacs as separate process from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, emacs, terminal

When I run the `emacs` text editor the process does not return so I cannot use the terminal which is obviously the default behavior.

I cannot find the switch or command in the `man` but I know it is something very simple.

How can I run `emacs` as a separate process so I can continue to use the terminal without opening a second one?

Comment: Run it in background: `emacs &`

Comment: Also, look for `emacsclient` not tu run many emacsen when one is enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start any program in the background by appending an ampersand to the command, `emacs &`.

There's a whole framework for working with backgrounded processes, see for example `man jobs`, `disown`, `fg`, `bg`, and try `Ctrl-Z` on a running process, which will suspend it and give you the terminal, allowing you to resume that process either in the foreground or background at your pleasure. Normally when your shell closes, all those programs will end, `disown` allows you to tell a program to keep running after you end your session.

Answer (score 2):

The `emacs --help` command is giving you a tip:

```
   --batch             do not do interactive display; implies -q
```

So run `emacs --batch` (or maybe `emacs --execute`*somecommand* ).

If you have a desktop (or some X11 display) and want `emacs` to open an X11 windows and give you back a shell prompt, run it in the background (e.g. `emacs &`) as many commented.

And I find very useful to start programs (or shells) within emacs, e.g. with  Emacs commands: `M-x shell`, or `M-x compile` (for `make` etc...), or `M-x gdb` for a debugger.

You usually start one single `emacs` at the beginning of a working day. You could use `emacsclient` (or set your `EDITOR` environment variable to it) for other editions using the same `emacs`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that Windows does have an equivalent to *nix's `&` for starting programs in a separate process:

```
start /b emacs Main.hs
```